# Text Encoding comes out corrupted after downloading from FTP

Tags: c#, .net

So i am making a program in c# with .net that uploads text files...
but everytime i upload a text file then download it on filezilla it comes out in chinese looking text..[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqDYS.png). im not sure if its because of encoding but if it helps heres my ftp code:

```
string ftpUsername = "#######";
            string ftpPassword = "##########";
            string localFilePath = path+ @"\" +FileName;
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
                client.UploadFile("ftp://###########/Logs/Text.txt", "STOR", localFilePath);
                File.Delete(path + @"\" + FileName);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the text file was coming out corrupted was not the upload method but the download method in FileZilla...

When you download you need to set the transfer type too binary...
this gets rid of the issue..